# How do I get AAD profile picture URL?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In the Azure Portal, under Azure Active Directory / Users, you can find image of the user.
It's like this `https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/Images/Users/<xxx>=.jpg?t=123456`

This `<xxx>` is kind of base64 encoded string with padding, so maybe you can convert it somehow from the object-id? I tried with no luck.

Is there a way to extract this URL through the Microsoft.Graph?

I tried to use `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photo`, but it's an object. And when you use `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photo/$value`, it's memory stream.

However, I'd like to use already created URL.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that's possible with MS Graph today. Downloading photos through Graph requires an access token so giving out a base64 encoded URL with a temporary auth token isn't something we currently do.  I agree this would make embedding profile pictures in apps much easier if you can just cache the image like a static resource.

If you want to submit a feature request you can use the Microsoft Graph uservoice at https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests

Answer (score -1):

```
$upn = 'user@domain.com'
Connect-AzureAD
$userid = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $upn).ObjectId

login-azurermaccount
$context = Get-AzureRmContext
$tenantId = $context.Tenant.Id
$refreshToken = $context.TokenCache.ReadItems().RefreshToken
$body = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$($refreshToken)&resource=74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6"
$apiToken = Invoke-RestMethod "https://login.windows.net/$tenantId/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

$header = @{
'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $apiToken.access_token
'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    'X-Requested-With'= 'XMLHttpRequest'
    'x-ms-client-request-id'= [guid]::NewGuid()
    'x-ms-correlation-id' = [guid]::NewGuid()
    }

$url = "https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/UserDetails/" + $userid
$imageurl = (Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $url –Headers $header –Method GET -Body $content -ErrorAction Stop).imageUrl
$imageurl
```